# How to get Time only from timestamp format in SQL?

Tags: timestamp

*select data from timestamp format the condition based on only time without year.*

```
***SELECT *
FROM invdata
WHERE timestamp >= '2018-07-12 15:48:30' 
  and timestamp <= '2018-07-12 16:44:31';***
```

Comment: What is your expected output? What output are you getting now?

Comment: This may vary from SQL engine to SQL engine. For example MySQL I'd recommend using the `SUBSTRING()` function (you may need to cast your timestamp into a string) -- other SQL engines may offer other methods of manipulating timestamp types: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your question is related to sql, you should consider adding that tag, but depends mostly on what database engine are you using, oracle, sql server, my sql, etc... For example in SQL Server there is a [format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Please add the tags that match your answer